# using strings in a Boolean statement in c

Tags: c

when I run with abc as the input argument nothing prints, why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

if (argv[1]=="abc")
{ 
printf("1");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare strings use `strcmp()` as

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "abc") == 0)
    printf("1");
```

The way your are checking using `==` will compare 2 `char *` pointers `argv[1]` and `"abc".

Answer (score 2):

`==` does not compare strings, you need to use the `strcmp` function